# RealmSwift: How to properly Adopt to RealmOptionalType protocol on UInt?

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have an object whose one of the properties from the server requires a type to be `UInt`, My project uses [RealmSwift](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) to store data locally once the data is parsed from the server.

Here is the sample use case:

```swift
import RealmSwift
import Foundation 

class MediaServerInfo: Object {
private var _hostPort = RealmOptional<UInt>()

}

// MARK: - Adopting to RealmOptionalType

// Here I am trying to adopt the protocol so that the _hostPort above can use RealmOptional<UInt>()

extension UInt: RealmOptionalType {
  public static func className() -> String {
    return "UInt"
  }
}
```

However, I am getting the following run time error as soon as I enter a page where the above class is used: -

```swift
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: ''RealmOptional<UInt>' is not a valid RealmOptional type.'
```

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm does not support the UInt type. The [Realm Cheatsheet](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#property-cheatsheet) shows the supported types along with this from the documentation

> RealmOptional supports Int, Float, Double, Bool, and all of the sized
> versions of Int (Int8, Int16, Int32, Int64).

One technique is to store the Int value in Realm as a backing var and leverage a non managed var to be the front.

```
class MediaServerInfo: Object {
   private let _hostPort = RealmOptional<Int>()

   var hostPort: UInt {
      get {
         let myInt = _hostPort.value ?? 0
         let u = UInt(myInt)
         return u
      }
    
     set {
        let myInt = Int(newValue)
        _hostPort.value = myInt
     }
   }
}
```

And use it like this when creating

```
let info = MediaServerInfo()
info.hostPort = UInt(42)
```

or to read

```
let x = info.hostPort
```

Comment: Hi, @Jay Thanks. I ended up doing almost similar approach.